# Bootstrap-sass : fieldset in bootstrap cannot be overriden

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm styling a rails web with bootstrap-sass. 
 import bootstrap, To override bootstrap

```
***fieldset
{
padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}***
```

I add a new fieldset description in  bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss
/*bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss*/

```
@import "bootstrap";
.
.

fieldset {
  padding: 1;
  margin: 1;
  border: 1;
}
```

However, my "fieldset" definition  is crossed out, the bootstrap "fieldset" still works.
When I look into the firebug, I found out, the fieldset defined by me is in line 5252.
the bootstrap "fieldset" is in line 742.

Why latter one cannot override the previous one?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a unit for your values: pixels, pt, em, etc.

Comment: To add to this, in some browsers in quirks mode `px` is the 'default' value. But, you should always define a unit after non-zero numbers, and I would argue when using 0 as well.